# Same term from custom taxonomy in two different custom post types?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I use a front end form to insert custom post types, an input is used for inserting terms (keywords) to a custom taxonomy for this custom post type.

I just noticed in the back-end when I view the terms list in the taxonomy. Only one unique term has been added even if I create multiple posts and use the same terms in each. Though in the back-end it does say how many custom posts the term is associated with.

From the back-end I get an error when trying to add a duplicate term. That's expected. I read though that WordPress in some cases creates a duplicate but the slug is unique.

On my custom post type single template page I have this function to list the terms

```
$keyword_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'keyword');
if(!empty($keyword_terms)){
  if(!is_wp_error( $keyword_terms )){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($keyword_terms as $term){
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'keyword').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

The slug / term link is the same on all the custom posts. Is that normal behavior of WordPress with custom taxonomies/terms? Is there a function to use to have the terms inserted and unique slugs generated?